# How to make a button to press on Python 3

Tags: python

How would I make a button that would activate a program? Sort of like a video game.
If you want to solve this question please take these requests into action.
 1. It needs to be in **Python 3**
2.it needs to be fairly simple.

Thanks

Comment: you should provide an example if you expect others to answer.

Comment: Try the problem first, before asking for help please.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you mean by activating a program, but in example below through the "command = Funtcion_name" you can get what you want by clicking on the button

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def pushTheButton():
    messagebox.showinfo("Outcome of pushing the button", " You have pushed the button!")

root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text = "Push me", command = pushTheButton)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```